# How To Send The Body Of Http Post Request using HTTPWebRequest

Tags: vb.net, system.net.httpwebrequest

I just want to POST a body data in a x-www-form-urlencoded format in a specific URL. I searched a lot but I only found how to send a parameter in an HTTP request post in VB.NET.

This is my code, but when I see the output it is just sending the post parameter:

```
Try

    Dim TextBox10 = "12637"
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://ptsv2.com/t/delh1-1545643919")
    request.Method = "POST"

    Dim postbody As String = "employee_id=" + TextBox1.Text + "&company_code=" + TextBox2.Text + "&reg_key=" + TextBox3.Text + ""
    Dim requestBody As String = "FormFieldName=Hello+World!"
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postbody)
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Dim response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse()
    Console.WriteLine((CType(response, HttpWebResponse)).StatusDescription)
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    TextBox4.Text = responseFromServer

    Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer)

    'Clean up the streams.  
    reader.Close()
    dataStream.Close()
    response.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox("NO DATA FOUND / CHECK INTERNET CONNECTION")
    TextBox4.Text = ""
    TextBox3.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
End Try
```

This is the output of the posted code:

[image: THIS IS THE IMAGE OF THE OUTPUT OF THE CODE POST]

How should I send the body data?

Comment: I don't see anything that would be an issue in your code... Make sure that the post body doesn't contain any invalid characters. You can escape such characters by applying [`Uri.EscapeUriString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapeuristring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) on your input before adding it to the body. If it still doesn't work, you can download [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to inspect the actual request sent from your computer.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to match your output, though, as the dump displays the parameter `FormFieldName` with value `Hello World!`, but in your code you never send that data (the `requestBody` parameter is never used).